# PHP how to get the value of content using echo?

Tags: php, html

I really don't know how to word this so i'll just say it. I am making a file system and am having a issue with creating folders. I can make the folders and delete them but the issue is that i can't get the specific name of the folder because of the way I list them. I need the name of the folder so I can upload files to them. I will post the code for the method i use to list them below.

```
if (is_dir($directory)) {
    if ($dh = opendir($directory)) {
        while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false) {
            if(is_dir($directory . $file)) {    
                if ($file != '.' && $file != '..') {
                    echo '<a href="'. $directory . $file.'" target="_blank">'.$file. ' ' . '<a href="interface.php?DelFile='.$file.'" class="delete" onClick="return confirmAction2()"> Delete </a><br><br />';
                }
            }
        }
        closedir($dh);
    }
}}
```

I really need help with this and hopefully this question won't get blocked due to my poor wording. Thanks in advance

Comment: $directory? not working?

Comment: I can read the directory but cannot get the specific name of the folder. I need this to move the files with the `move_uploaded_file()` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to set a session like @HeyItsProdigy Said

Answer (score 0):

I changed the listing system to the following to fix it!

```
if (is_dir($directory)) {
                if ($dh = opendir($directory)) {
                    while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false) {
                        if(is_dir($directory . $file)) {    
                            if ($file != '.' && $file != '..') {
                                echo '<form method="post" action="interface.php"><input type="submit" value="'.$file.'" name="'.$file.'"></form><a href="interface.php?DelFile='.$file.'" class="delete" onClick="return confirmAction2()"> Delete </a><br><br />';
                                if (isset($_POST[$file])) {
                                    session_start();
                                    $_SESSION['folder_name'] = $file;
                                    echo '<META HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" Content="0; URL='.$directory . $file.'" target="_blank" >';    
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    closedir($dh);
                }
            }}
```